# Python ImportError with libgdal, undefined symbol: opj_codec_set_threads

Tags: python, gdal, linux, jpg

GDAL and its Python 3 bindings have been installed through `apt` package manager for weeks, but, suddenly:

```py
from osgeo import GDAL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-61e0eefce4de> in <module>()
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>()
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

/usr/local/pythonenv/smap_l4c-env/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
    245         return load_package(name, filename)

/usr/local/pythonenv/smap_l4c-env/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 
    345 else:

ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: opj_codec_set_threads
```

The same error, with slightly different Traceback, is obtained with `import gdal`.

I didn't recognize this symbol name, `opj_codec_set_threads` so I looked it up online. It's apparently part of the OpenJPEG library. I recalled that I had recently run some legacy setup script for another project with OpenJPEG as a dependency. That legacy setup script apparently installed an older verison of OpenJPEG (v2.1.0) on top of what `apt` had installed (v2.3.0) when I first setup the machine.

I tried reinstalling OpenJPEG from `apt`:

```sh
sudo apt install --reinstall libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev
sudo ldconfig
```

**This did not solve the problem.** I tried re-installing GDAL and its bindings:

```sh
sudo apt install --reinstall gdal-bin libgdal-dev python-gdal python3-gdal
```

**Still no good.**

Answer (score 2):

The older version of OpenJPEG was installed with `cmake`. **I gathered that GDAL's shared objects from OpenJPEG (expecting v2.3.0) were misplaced since the install but it wasn't initially obvious where the v2.1.0 files were, how to remove, or update the links.**

Luckily, `cmake` creates a file called `install_manifest.txt` to keep track of its installed files. **I finally used `cmake` to *uninstall* v2.1.0:**

```sh
cd /my/openjpeg-2.1.0/install/dir
xargs rm < install_manifest.txt
```

**Then, I was able to reinstall OpenJPEG, GDAL, and its Python bindings.**

```sh
sudo apt install --reinstall libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev
sudo apt install --reinstall gdal-bin libgdal-dev python-gdal python3-gdal
```

Now I can `import gdal` without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

To spell this out a bit more, opj_codec_set_threads was introduced in OpenJPEG version 2.3.0, and the above error is due to an older version of this library.